# Открытие ссылки required и type="submit"

Tags: javascript, html, css

подскажите как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалась ссылка, только если первые два поля заполнены.

```
<form>
   <input type="email"  placeholder="Введите email" name="email-popup" required /> <br>
   <input type="login" placeholder="Введите логин" name="login"  required /> <br>
   <a target="_blank" href="https://vk.com"><input type="submit" value="Отправить"/></a>
 </form>
```

Comment: Заворачивать кнопку в ссылку — это максимально странно. Чего вы хотели этим добиться?

Comment: Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалась ссылка

Comment: Не фишинговый сайт случайно?

Comment: Нет конечно, обычное заполнение формы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю чтобы форма нормально работала вместо ссылки нужно написать адрес сюда

```html
<form action="vk.com"> 
   <input type="email" placeholder="Введите email" name="email-popup" required=""> <br>
   <input type="login" placeholder="Введите логин" name="login" required=""> <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```